# Power shell to create user and set Regional Configuration

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Can anyone help. I'm creating users on our exchange 2016 system by using the following cmd's

```
Enable-MailUser -Identity "joe.bloggs" -ExternalEmailAddress 'joe.bloggs@domain.co.uk'

Get-MailUser -Identity "joe.bloggs" | Enable-Mailbox

Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "joe.bloggs" -User MailboxAdmins -AccessRights Fullaccess -InheritanceType all

Set-MailboxRegionalConfiguration -Identity "joe.bloggs" -TimeZone "GMT Standard Time" -DateFormat "dd/MM/yyyy" -Language "en-GB" -TimeFormat "HH:mm"
```

They all work however the Set-MailboxRegionalConfiguration always throws an error. I have to wait a few minutes and then run it again and it completes. I believe it is because the Enable user cmd is still working in the background.

Does anyone know of a way of changing it so that the cmd runs after the mailbox has been enabled?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could add `sleep` interval into your script to give exchange time to sort out the account before running the `Set-MailboxRegionalConfiguration` cmdlet.

```
Enable-MailUser -Identity "joe.bloggs" -ExternalEmailAddress 'joe.bloggs@domain.co.uk'

Get-MailUser -Identity "joe.bloggs" | Enable-Mailbox

Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "joe.bloggs" -User MailboxAdmins -AccessRights Fullaccess -InheritanceType all

Sleep -Seconds 30

Set-MailboxRegionalConfiguration -Identity "joe.bloggs" -TimeZone "GMT Standard Time" -DateFormat "dd/MM/yyyy" -Language "en-GB" -TimeFormat "HH:mm"
```